# [OleDbException (0x80040e14): Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'PCName= <%# Eval('PCName')%>'.]

Tags: asp.net, sql, database

without where command the result appared like this repeat all record every time after  product category

NEW LAPTOP
Acer
Dell
HP
Kingston
Sony
USB FLASH DRIVE
Acer
Dell
HP
Kingston
Sony
USED LAPTOP
Acer
Dell
HP
Kingston
Sony

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server"></head>
<body>    
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <li><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PCName") %>' /></li>
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource2" runat="server" DataFile="~/Database/PDetail.mdb" 
SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [PBName] FROM [PDETAIL] WHERE PCName= <%# Eval('PCName')%> " />
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource2">
    <ItemTemplate> <li> <%# Eval("PBName")%> </li> </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>

<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server"  DataFile="~/Database/PDetail.mdb" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [PCName] FROM [PDETAIL]" />
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: ' ' IS WORK BUT AFTER THAT THIS ERROR OCCURS

Answer (score 0):

```
<ItemTemplate>

<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource2" 
      runat="server" DataFile="~/Database/PDetail.mdb" 
      SelectCommand='<%# "SELECT DISTINCT [PBName] FROM [PDETAIL] WHERE PCName= " +  (char)39 + Eval("PCName") + (char)39 %>'  />

</ItemTemplate>


 (char)39 is for '
```

Comment: already 2 Repeater in code but error is given above i think that the result of <%# Eval("PCName")%> store in string var and var used in sql query and have some initial value

Comment: I hope you don't have any apostrophe in your names...However I think you need to try another approach. On the ItemDataBound event of the parent repeater call item.FindControl("AccessDataSource2"), then convert it to the proper control and the add to the SelectParameters the value found in item.Data. This way you won't have errors because of unwanted literals in the names and you creating secure statements which don't suffer from SQL injection.

Comment: tell me how can i define string var and store value in it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470068/repeater-within-a-gridview-repeater-only-pulling-from-the-last-gridview-idcau
see this, is near your situation